# Understanding a complex one line code - Big Mart Sales Data Set Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have been trying to learn to analyze **Big Mart Sales Data Set** from this [website](http://unsupervisedlearning.co.uk/2017/11/22/project-3-big-mart-sales-prediction-part-1/). I am unable to decode a line of code which is little bit complex. I tried to understand demystify it but I wasn't able to. Kindly help me understand this line at

***In [26]***

```
df['Item_Visibility_MeanRatio'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Item_Visibility']/visibility_item_avg['Item_Visibility'][visibility_item_avg.index == x['Item_Identifier']][0],axis=1).astype(float)
```

Thankyou very much in advance. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Item_Visibility_MeanRatio']
```

This is the new column name

```
= df.apply(lambda x:
```

applying a function to the dataframe

```
x['Item_Visibility']
```

take the Item_Visibility column from the original dataframe

```
/visibility_item_avg['Item_Visibility'][visibility_item_avg.index == x['Item_Identifier']][0]
```

divide where the Item_Visibility column in the new pivot table where the Item_Identifier is equal to the Item_Identifier in the original dataframe

```
,axis=1)
```

apply along the columns (horizontally)

```
.astype(float)
```

convert to float type

Also, it looks like `.apply` is used a lot on the link you attached. It should be noted that apply is generally the slow way to do things, and there are usually alternatives to avoid using apply.

Comment: Thankyou very much @user13802115 for your response. But can you please explain why `[0]` in the `/visibility_item_avg['Item_Visibility'][visibility_item_avg.index == x['Item_Identifier']][0]` and please suggest what can be used in place `.apply` to make it faster. Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1):

Lets go thorough it step by step:

```
df['Item_Visibility_MeanRatio']
```

This part is creating a column in the data frame and its name is `Item_Visibility_MeanRatio`.

```
df.apply(lambda...)
```

Apply a function along an axis of the Data frame.

```
x['Item_Visibility']
```

It is getting the data from `Item_Visibility` column in the data frame.

```
visibility_item_avg['Item_Visibility'][visibility_item_avg.index == x['Item_Identifier']][0]
```

This part finds the indexes that `visibility_item_avg` index is equal to `df['Item_Identifier']`.This will lead to a list. Then it will get the elements in `visibility_item_avg['Item_Visibility']` that its index is equal to what was found in the previous part. **`[0]` at the end is to find the first element of the outcome array.**

```
axis=1
```

1 : apply function to each row.

```
astype(float)
```

This is for changing the value types to float.
To make the code easy to grab, you can always split it to separate parts and digest it little by little.

To make the code faster you can do Vectorization instead of applying lambda.
Refer to the link [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06).